# Does a lambda function require any header files?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I usually code on my mac, and I'm not great about including headers (clang seems to give a lot of leeway on this). As a result, I often do not know what provided functions I use belong to which header.

In the case of lambda expressions, do they need to include any header? I checked on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda, but I did not see any information on this.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't. Lambdas are a language feature not a library feature. You *can* bind them to `std::function` which lives in `<functional>` but you don't *have* to.

You can verify this easily, the following code [compiles as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/3Y4EbK) despite not including *any* header whatsoever:

```
int main() {
  auto f = [](){};
  f();
}
```

Comment: oh I see, if you declare it using:

`auto f = [](){};`, would this syntax require including `<functional>`?

Comment: @David No. The lambda has some implementation defined type.

Comment: but if you instead did `std::function<double(int)> f = [](int a) -> double {...};` this would require including functional right?

Comment: @David Yes, exactly.

Comment: @David: Yes. `std::function` is defined in the library, and you need to include the header that defines (or at least declares) it.

Comment: @David it is recommended to avoid `std::function` because it's pretty heavy, unless you do need it i.e. you need type erasure.

Comment: *"You can verify this easily"*, C++ is complex enough than compiling (we already have to use correct flags to disable extensions, which are generally not the default) is just a (good) hint.

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair enough. Maybe I should have said *confirm* rather than *verify*?

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are part of the language and so don't need a header to be used, just as you don't need to include a header to define an ordinary function.

Comment: Counterpoint: `auto x = {0};` requires `<initializer_list>` and `typeid` requires `<typeinfo>`.

Comment: Because both expressions use types defined in the standard library,  but good point.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
int main()
{
    auto x = [](int i) {
        return i;
    };

    x(2);
}
```

will be generate to something like

```
int main()
{
    struct X {
        inline int operator()(int i) const { return i; }
    } x;

    x(2);
}
```

So it no need to include any header